# Oracle : Update command using where clause is case sensitive?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqWcv.png)

SQL> select *from ORA_DEPT;

DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_NAME

---

```
       10 HR
       10 Account
       20 TEST
       30 QA
       40 Dev
```

SQL> update ORA_DEPT set department_name='PR' where department_name='account';

0 rows updated.

SQL> update ORA_DEPT set department_name='PR' where department_name='dev';

0 rows updated.

SQL> update ORA_DEPT set department_name='PR' where department_name='dev';

0 rows updated

Comment: Of course `Dev` and 'dev' differ literally. Check out the difference character by character by `SELECT dump('dev'), dump('Dev') FROM dual`.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is generally case insensitive, in the sense that object names (table, column, procedure, bind variable etc.) are generally case insensitive. (They *can* be made case sensitive, but that's irrelevant here.)

You are applying the concept to **data**, namely to strings of characters. There is no language on Earth where strings are not case sensitive.

If you want to make the `where` clause case insensitive, you can do so explicitly:

```
...
where lower(department_name) = 'account'
```

Or, you can use the "nuclear option" - you can force all such comparisons to be case insensitive, by changing your NLS options. Namely:

```
alter session set nls_comp = linguistic;
alter session set nls_sort = binary_ci;
```

Note that you need **both** changes; if the `comp` parameter is `binary`, or if the `sort` parameter is not `*_ci`, you won't get what you want.

Use the "nuclear option" at your own risk, and only if you have a very good reason for it.

And, in any case, in your `update` statement, if you give the value `'PR'`, don't ever expect that it will be saved as `'pr'`, or vice versa; not unless you have a trigger that does that in the middle of the process, or some other kind of silly thing like that.